# The @ sign in Laravel web.php route files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What exactly the '@' sign stand for in laravel route file web.php
Ex: Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');? please don't tell me what this code does I already know that. but the question is why the @ sign??
The'@' sign is not a method but the index is. so what is name of this @ sign and what exactly it does?  I'm just curious to know why??? the @ sign.

Comment: "at"... "HomeController" means the Controller which is going to be used and then "at" the function..."at index function". So, we translate "HomeController@index" to "I want the HomeController at the index function".

Comment: AFAIK The only purpose it serves is to separate the controller class name from the controller method name. A colon or any other character not usable in a classname/namespace could have been used as well, but the at sign was chosen instead.

Comment: From Router.php: `Now we can split the controller and method out of the action string so that we  can call them appropriately on the class. This controller and method are in in the Class@method format and we need to explode them out then use them.`. Why the @ symbol? Ask the developers, they're the ones that chose it.

Comment: @JeffLambert Thanks a lot!! this is the answer that I was expecting so I now understand. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments have mostly covered it, but I will add a few notes, because I think its an interesting question.

#### Technical usage

We can see by looking at the source, it's simply a good ol' fashioned `explode` statement, splitting the Controller from the method:

> **Proceeding comment**
>   If the binding has an @ sign, we will assume it's being used to delimit
>   the class name from the bind method name. This allows for bindings
>   to run multiple bind methods in a single class for convenience.

```
        $segments = explode('@', $binding);
```

On a technical front, the "why" as mentioned by @JeffLambert is that any character that *isn't* a valid character for a class or method name, would work as a delimiter.

#### Non Technical

As mentioned by @aynber, you would need to ask the developers to get a concrete guess. However I will hazard a (very reasonable) guess:

`@` is commonly used in editors to mark a method. For example, in sublime, open the command panel and type `@` and it will show you a list of all methods in the current class/file:

[image]

I would also argue that it reads quite naturally. Use `controller` "at" `this method`.